# Number of positive integer solutions

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many positive integer solutions of the equation:
$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_p = n$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are odd numbers and other $x_i$'s are even numbers ?

Is there any theorm about such equation?

Comment: Zero when $n$ is odd.  Consider compositions of $\frac{n}{2}+1$ when $n$ is even

Answer (score 2):

Add $1$ to each of $x_1$ and $x_2$, and divide throughout by $2$ to get $y_1+\ldots+y_p=\frac{n}{2}+1$, all of the $y_i$'s positive. Then number of integer solutions which boils down to
[star and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.

Comment: Careful, zero is even. You want to subtract 1 from $x_1$ and $x_2$, adding up to $n - 2$, divide by $2$ and get all $y_i$ non-negative adding up to $n/2 - 1$, with $n$ even.

Comment: @vonbrand "positive integer solutions", we don't need to consider zeros...